# How can I get current wifi link speed in Swift?

Tags: android, swift, performance, hyperlink, wifi

Is it possible to get current **wifi** **link speed** in Swift?
Ex: 72Mbps

Known method in andriod Method: `WifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getLinkSpeed()`

Answer (score -1):

You can call it.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html#getLinkSpeed()

```
wifiInfo.getLinkSpeed();
```

Comment: Thanks @WJ JEONG! But I am looking for the similar method in Swift.